# Including PJSIP-Library and writing makefile

Tags: c, makefile, include-path, pjsip

im new to writing makefile. Now im trying to use pjsip c-library, which i installed in my home-directory. I took a little snipped and tried to compile it. Had some errors and so i searched for an solution, so i found out i had to include this library's to the search path. Further there is a possibility to declare them in the makefile, so i tried the 2nd solution.

Here my makefile:

```
pjpath=home/pi/pjproject-2.4.5
LIB=-L/$(pjpath)/pjlib/lib -L/$(pjpath)/pjlib-util/lib -L/$(pjpath)/pjnath/lib -L/$(pjpath)/pjmedia/lib -L/$(pjpath)/pjsip/lib
INC=-I/$(pjpath)/pjlib/include -I/$(pjpath)/pjlib-util/include -I/$(pjpath)/pjnath/include -I/$(pjpath)/pjmedia/include -I/$(pjpath)/pjsip/include

all:
        gcc -o test $(INC) simple_pjsua.c $(LIB) -lpj -lpjlib -lpjnath -lpjmedia -lpjmedia-audiodev -lpjmedia-codec -lpjmedia-videodev -lpjsdp -lpjsip -lpjsip-simple -lpjsip-ua -lpjsua -lpjsua2
clean: 
        rm simple_pjsua.o test
```

and here my c-file simple_pjsua.c:

> ```
> #define PJ_IS_LITTLE_ENDIAN 1
> #define PJ_IS_BIG_ENDIAN 0 
> #include <pjsua-lib/pjsua.h>
> #define THIS_FILE "App"
> #define SIP_USER "demo-user2"
> #define SIP_DOMAIN "sip:192.168.2.59"
> #define SIP_PASSWD "123456"
>     static void on_incoming_call(pjsua_acc_id acc_id, pjsua_call_id call_id, pjsip_rx_data *rdata);
>     static void on_call_state(pjsua_call_id call_id, pjsip_event *e);
>     static void on_call_media_state(pjsua_call_id call_id);
>     static void error_exit(const char *title, pj_status_t status);
>
>     int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
>             printf("Hello World");
>             return 0;
>     }
>
>     static void on_incoming_call(pjsua_acc_id acc_id, pjsua_call_id call_id, pjsip_rx_data *rdata){
>             pjsua_call_info ci; 
>             PJ_UNUSED_ARG(acc_id);
>             PJ_UNUSED_ARG(rdata);
>             pjsua_call_get_info(call_id, &ci);
>
>             PJ_LOG(3,(THIS_FILE, "Incoming call from %.*s!!", (int) ci.remote_info.slen, ci.remote_info.ptr));
>
>             /* Automatically answer incoming calls with 200/OK */
>             pjsua_call_answer(call_id, 200, NULL, NULL);
>     }
>
>     static void on_call_state(pjsua_call_id call_id, pjsip_event *e){
>             pjsua_call_info ci; 
>
>             PJ_UNUSED_ARG(e);
>
>             pjsua_call_get_info(call_id, &ci);
>             PJ_LOG(3,(THIS_FILE, "Call %d state=%.*s", call_id, (int) ci.state_text.slen, ci.state_text.ptr));
>     }
>
>     static void on_call_media_state(pjsua_call_id call_id){
>             pjsua_call_info ci; 
>             pjsua_call_get_info(call_id, &ci);
>
>             if (ci.media_status == PJSUA_CALL_MEDIA_ACTIVE) {
>                     pjsua_conf_connect(ci.conf_slot, 0); 
>                     pjsua_conf_connect(0, ci.conf_slot);
>             }   
>     }
>
>     static void error_exit(const char *title, pj_status_t status){
>             pjsua_perror(THIS_FILE, title, status);
>             pjsua_destroy();
>             exit(1);
>     }
> ```

and this is my output of the makefile:

```
    gcc -o test -I/home/pi/pjproject-2.4.5/pjlib/include -I/home/pi/pjproject-2.4.5/pjlib-util/include -I/home/pi/pjproject-2.4.5/pjnath/include -I/home/pi/pjproject-2.4.5/pjmedia/include -I/home/pi/pjproject-2.4.5/pjsip/include simple_pjsua.c -L/home/pi/pjproject-2.4.5/pjlib/lib -L/home/pi/pjproject-2.4.5/pjlib-util/lib -L/home/pi/pjproject-2.4.5/pjnath/lib -L/home/pi/pjproject-2.4.5/pjmedia/lib -L/home/pi/pjproject-2.4.5/pjsip/lib -lpj -lpjlib -lpjnath -lpjmedia -lpjmedia-audiodev -lpjmedia-codec -lpjmedia-videodev -lpjsdp -lpjsip -lpjsip-simple -lpjsip-ua -lpjsua -lpjsua2 
In file included from /home/pi/pjproject-2.4.5/pjlib/include/pj/config.h:288:0,
                 from /home/pi/pjproject-2.4.5/pjlib/include/pj/types.h:33,
                 from /home/pi/pjproject-2.4.5/pjsip/include/pjsip/sip_config.h:27,
                 from /home/pi/pjproject-2.4.5/pjsip/include/pjsip/sip_types.h:34,
                 from /home/pi/pjproject-2.4.5/pjsip/include/pjsip.h:24,
                 from /home/pi/pjproject-2.4.5/pjsip/include/pjsua-lib/pjsua.h:30,
                 from simple_pjsua.c:3:
/home/pi/pjproject-2.4.5/pjlib/include/pj/config_site.h:3:35: warning: extra tokens at end of #include directive [enabled by default]
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpj
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpjlib
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpjnath
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpjmedia
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpjmedia-audiodev
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpjmedia-codec
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpjmedia-videodev
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpjsdp
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpjsip
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpjsip-simple
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpjsip-ua
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpjsua
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpjsua2
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
makefile:6: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

I also found a useful [site](http://www.pjsip.org/using.htm) which explains how it's done, although i couldn't yet figure it out.

Comment: You missed the `-l` arguments to actually link with the libraries.

Comment: i tried multiple variations of the -l option, but non worked for me. Can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: Update the post with what you tried.

Comment: so after a while of searching i figured out i had to give every single library explicit on compiling. But now he searches on the wrong path.

Comment: The format for arguments to `-l` is `-l$shortname` so `-lpj` or `-lpjsua` (you can use full paths to files but that's rarer). Try the correct arguments and see what happens.

Comment: `gcc -L/home/pi/pjproject-2.4.5/pjlib/lib/ -lpjsua -o test simple_pjsua.c` spits `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpjsua` and `gcc -L/home/pi/pjproject-2.4.5/pjlib/lib/ -lpj -o test simple_pjsua.c ` same

Comment: also giving path like `gcc -l/home/pi/pjproject-2.4.5/pjlib/lib/pj -o test simple_pjsua.c`also isn't working :(

Comment: If the library file is really `libpj-armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabihfi.so` then you might need to use `-lpj-armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabihfi` but I'm not sure (I'd have assumed the cross-compiler stuff would handle that but maybe not).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so i found the the simplest solution at this [Site](https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting_Started_Using), in the section makefile with version 1.6 or later.

```
# If your application is in a file named myapp.cpp or myapp.c
# this is the line you will need to build the binary.
all: myapp

myapp: myapp.cpp
        $(CC) -o $@ $< `pkg-config --cflags --libs libpjproject`

clean:
        rm -f myapp.o myop
```

Worked for me, but there was one clue which i stumble over.
This is important and is also described at the bottom of the page i linked. If you notice there are spaces towards the bottom of the file (before $(CC) and rm, these are a single tab, not spaces. This is important, or otherwise make command will fail with "missing separator" error.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the first warning is from the library code, your code isn't guilty.

Then, always specify link libraries *after* all of your source or object files. By default GNU linker doesn't remember the symbols from libraries which haven't been referenced yet, so it simply drops out all of your `-lsomelib` if that `somelib` hasn't been referenced by a previous object or library.

So, I bet, the line

```
 gcc -o test $(INC) simple_pjsua.c $(LIB)
```

would help you (or at least this particular error would be resolved).